# Maven with Surefire (TestNG) is slow after update to MacOS Sierra

Tags: java, maven, testng, macos-sierra

Before the update my MacBook Pro to MacOs Sierra, the command:

```
mvn clean install -U
```

took about 40 sec to run, with several hundreds of tests in several maven sub-modules.

After the update to MacOS Sierra, with no changes to the code, the same command takes over 12 minutes. It looks to me that the when the Surefire plugin is going to print the result of the current module, it hangs for 2-3 minutes before continuing. The speed of the test-execution up to this point is as fast as before the update to MacOS Sierra.

Example of a TestNG result printout from on of the modules:

```
Tests run: 101, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 167.854 sec

Results :

Tests run: 101, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Does anyone know the reasons behind this?

Comment: I am having everything in Java related to networking slower after updating. Launching a Spring app went from 26 seconds to 75 seconds. Another one went from 15 seconds to 150 seconds. My guess is it is related to networking based on what I am seeing, but not sure yet.

Comment: The fix is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33289897/387927

Comment: That does not solve it for me, the comment from David Dossot. Will come back with more info after I have done some more testing.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I've had this exact problem (and spent the last 6 hours trying to solve it). My problem was that my HostName wasn't set.

Check that:

```
sudo scutil --get LocalHostName
```

Matches:

```
sudo scutil --get HostName
```

And if they don't, use:

```
sudo scutil --set HostName [YOUR_HOST_NAME]
```

To fix it.

Comment: Yes this solved my problem. But you made a slight typo. It should be

    "sudo scutil --set HostName [YOUR_HOST_NAME]"

Comment: This has been bugging me for months.  THANKS!  I'd love to know how you figured this out if you ever have time to write down your approach to troubleshooting this.

Comment: Thank you so much! Had a lot of struggles with this one!

Comment: Thank you! So much wasted time waiting on tests could have been averted if I found this sooner..

Comment: Thank you so much! You can't imagine how much time this fix is going to save me :-D

Comment: Thanks this just caught me up on a recent combination of surefire/testng. I'd be interested to know how you came across this solution as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, incredible difference after upgrade to MacOS 10.14 (Mojave)

no HostName set
`Running TestSuite
Tests run: 332, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 192.406 sec - in TestSuite`

HostName set

`Running TestSuite
Tests run: 332, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.23 sec - in TestSuite`

I really need to dig into this. This seems like some major bug.

Comment: Weird stuff, just ran into this with a project I have been working on for 5 month. Suddenly 9min build time instead of 50secs. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case both `LocalHostName` and `HostName` were matching already. Also, I tried adding hostname in `/etc/hosts` as suggested in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/33289897/387927. Both have no impact on the time taken for the maven build.

The following was the output of `mvn -version`

```
Apache Maven 3.8.6
Maven home: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.6/libexec
Java version: 11.0.12, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.12.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "11.6.x", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"
```

But my os version is `12.5.1`

I uninstalled and reinstalled `java version 11.0.16`. After this, the output of `mvn -version`is as follows

```
Apache Maven 3.8.6 (84538c9988a25aec085021c365c560670ad80f63)
Maven home: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/maven/3.8.6/libexec
Java version: 11.0.16, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.16.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "12.5.1", arch: "aarch64", family: "mac"
```

Then the build time was reduced from 9 minutes to 2 minutes.