# Why is hello-world example project so slow to startup in micronaut?

Tags: micronaut

Is it normal for Micronaut to take ~75 seconds to start it's hello-world example project?  This seems very much at odds with the way the framework has been described.   I am running this on a MacBook pro with decent specs and the project was created following the steps in the Micronaut User Guide without any customization. The same happens whether I start from my IDE or the uber jar.

```
java -jar ./libs/hello-world-0.1-all.jar
04:53:39.715 [main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 76248ms. Server Running: http://localhost:8080
```

FWIW, I was intrigued by Micronaut since I stumbled across it a few months back in part because Spring has become too bloated and I was looking for alternatives.  I was planning to build a simple REST service and compare it with the same service in SpringBoot but I view this slowness as a blocker.

At first I was thinking that this might be the Annotation Processors doing their IOC stuff but, that can't be the culprit because it is just as slow using the uber jar which shouldn't incur this cost.  Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289695/inetaddress-getlocalhost-slow-to-run-30-seconds/33289897#33289897

Comment: "At first I was thinking that this might be the Annotation Processors doing their IOC stuff but, that can't be the culprit because it is just as slow using the uber jar which shouldn't incur this cost." - The annotation processors aren't involved at runtime at all.  Our annotation processors are invoked at compile time.

Comment: That is true if you are using the uber jar or running with something like `./gradlew run` or `./mvnw exec:exec`.  Annotation processing is not part of startup time any of those scenarios.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check your hostname with:

```
hostname
```

and add it to `/etc/hosts` for `127.0.0.1` and `::1` addresses.

According to Micronaut's official guide there is a known bug causing delay when calling `java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost()` on Mac OS when the hostname is not present in the `/etc/hosts` file.

*/etc/hosts*

```
127.0.0.1       localhost <hostname>
::1             localhost <hostname>
```

https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#problems

Comment: Thank you both for your answers.  Your suggestion worked and fixed the problem...startup is now around 1 second.  I'm looking forward to now running my initial experiments to compare the new framework with SpringBoot to see if it is a better fit for some of our use cases.    ---   `java -jar ./libs/hello-world-0.1-all.jar
18:25:26.524 [main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 911ms. Server Running: http://localhost:8080`