# Threads getting locked due to InetAddress.getLocalHost()

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using this in a logging filter in a SpringBoot application, almost all the main threads are going in lock state due to **InetAddress.getLocalHost()**. What could be the possible reason and how can I fix this?

```
private void populateMandatoryDetailsFromRequest(final HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest)
        throws UnknownHostException {
    ThreadContext.put(CO_HOST_ADDRESS.value(), InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
    ThreadContext.put(CO_REQUEST_URI.value(), httpServletRequest.getRequestURI());
}
```

Comment: I would say it is a duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33289695/inetaddress-getlocalhost-slow-to-run-30-seconds. Instead of doing the lookup over and over, I would suggest doing the lookup once (at startup) and reuse. That will save the continuous lookup and increase performance.

Answer (score 0):

That surprises me. I can only guess it's related to the fact that [`getLocalHost()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost()) does a DNS name lookup to get the IP address. You could try

```
httpServletRequest.getLocalAddr()
```

instead, if that would that give you the same IP in your use case.