# Couchbase connection taking too much of time in java

Tags: java, database-connection, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

We are creating environment variable like this.

```
        logger.info(marker, "Couchbase## initializeBuckets tracerConfig start time {}", LocalDateTime.now());

    ThresholdLoggingTracerConfig.Builder tracer = ThresholdLoggingTracerConfig.builder()
            .emitInterval(Duration.ofMillis(tracerConfig.getLong("emitInterval", 20000L)))
            .kvThreshold(Duration.ofMillis(tracerConfig.getLong("kvThreshold", 20000L)))
            .queryThreshold(Duration.ofMillis(tracerConfig.getLong("n1qlThreshold", 60000L)))
            .sampleSize(tracerConfig.getInteger("sampleSize", 5)).searchThreshold(Duration.ofSeconds(60));

    logger.info(marker, "Couchbase## initializeBuckets before environment time {}", LocalDateTime.now());

    environment = ClusterEnvironment.builder()
        .thresholdLoggingTracerConfig(tracer)
        .retryStrategy(BestEffortRetryStrategy.INSTANCE)
        .ioConfig(IoConfig.enableDnsSrv(false))
        .timeoutConfig(TimeoutConfig.connectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(
                couchbaseConfig.getLong(CONNECT_TIMEOUT, CONNECT_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)))
            .queryTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(couchbaseConfig.
                getLong(QUERY_TIMEOUT, QUERY_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE)))
            .kvTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(couchbaseConfig.getLong(KV_TIMEOUT, KV_TIMEOUT_DEFAULT_VALUE))))
        .build();

    logger.info(marker, "Couchbase## initializeBuckets after environment time {}", LocalDateTime.now());
```

**It takes around 6-8 seconds to crate environment** environment variable. Even if we remove thresholdLoggingTracerConfig or use just below code to create default environment, it remains same.

```
environment = ClusterEnvironment.builder()
```

Is any better way to optimize this creation and also can you please help me to understand why it takes this much time to create environment.

Comment: What version of the Couchbase Java SDK are you using? And what version of Couchbase Server?

Comment: sdk : 3.4.0 server : 6.6.0

Comment: Are you using Log4j2? If so, the delay might be due to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75647869/log4j-2-20-0-takes-several-seconds-to-initialize

Comment: no.. we are using slf4j

Comment: SLF4J is a logging facade that routes logging requests to a specific logger implementation (like logback, logj42, etc.). Which SLF4J binding are you using?

Comment: Cross-reference to discussion on Couchbase Forum: https://www.couchbase.com/forums/t/environment-creation-is-taking-too-much-time/37151